Android Studio Prevent user using Root Activity Launcher
I want to prevent users from launching my app's activity using third-party tools like Root Activity Launcher, How should I do?
My app provide Super User to use my app more convenient, I just don't want my app be launched by informal methods.
What I Tried:

Declare android:exported="false" in Manifest for other activities except LAUNCHER Activity.
Declare a variable that init in LAUNCHER Activity.

Result:

Cannot prevent root user using Root Activity Launcher.

If user Launch the app with Root Activity Launcher directly before open my app, because the variable haven't init, so I can judgment with it and remind the user. But if the user already opened my app( LAUNCHER Activity ), then using Root Activity Launcher to Launch cannot be judgment.


